# Visual Studio Code: search/find Code lines only, disregard text in comments

Tags: visual-studio-code

```
// foo
let foo = "bar";

let baz = "foo"; // baz and foo

function do(){ /* do foo */
  return "foo";
}
```

Is there a way to search and find only the **code** lines? (I couldn't find any blog/post or extension)

So a search for **foo** returns:

```
let foo = "bar";
let baz = "foo"; // baz and foo
  return "foo";
```

Comment: What are you going to do with the results?

Comment: Give this a try: `(.*(?<!((\/\/)|(\/\*)).*?)\bfoo\b.*)|(.*(?<=\*\/).*\bfoo\b.*)`  that'll only work in the find widget not the search across files panel because the search panel will not allow infinite length lookbehinds which the find widget can handle.  I also included this test case: ` /* do foo */ function doo (){  foo`.  See https://regex101.com/r/GcRAGq/1

Comment: Wicked regexp. The foo was an example of course. In my real code it mainly is class Names. One is ``Hexed`` (no kidding)  Used 20 times in documentation, only 5 times in code. While coding I keep navigating between those 5 code lines. 5 split screens is unworkable. And haven't found a bookmark extension that, **with one key press** can cycle between the 5 code locations, like I can with Find & F3